# Next.js failing to query another local server in getInitialProps

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to query a rails server running locally through getInitialProps, however I keep getting an error 
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect`
I know there's nothing wrong with the rails server as I can query it just fine through Postman and another non-next react application. Is there some extra config you need to pass to `next.config.js` to query another locally running server?

Comment: What is your setup? docker?

Comment: are your local server and next app both running on the same port? did you try to send a request through axios on say a button or something to check whether the issue is with next or just getinitialprops?

Comment: not running on docker and running on different ports (3000 and 8080). I just tried with just a button and it works just fine so something must be going wrong with the server side request in getInitialProps.

Comment: Figured it out. Because the next server was making requests to 127.0.0.0:3000 and not localhost:3000, the rails server was refusing requests. Just needed to pass the rails server a binding flag in order for the server to accept requests from any network interface